how to verify if returned mail spam was relayed through my server
I host my own mail server using postfix/dovecot.  Recently, I've gotten a few "email rejected" emails acting like my server sent spam from an account that doesn't exist on my server.  I've searched through /var/log/mail.log for any occurrences of that account name, or the receiving server's name, etc, but can't find anything.  So the possibilities I can come up with are either:

these are fake rejection emails being sent to me for some reason
I'm not searching for the right stuff in the logs, or not searching the right logs, etc
Somehow my server is sending email without logging it

Is there any way to really confirm which one of these is the case?  I don't want my host to get mad at me for unknowingly relaying spam
For reference, I've tried commands like:
cat mail.log |grep -v "relay=local" |grep "relay=" |grep "status=sent"
cat mail.log | grep submission
grep -o 'to=<[^@]@.[^>]' /var/log/mail.log
cat mail.log | grep <HOST URL>
cat mail.log | grep <SENDER USER NAME>

I also added default_transport = error: This server sends mail only locally. to my postfix/main.cf file, which supposedly disables all outbound mail, but still got another 'email rejected' type mail returned the next day

The header of the email contains all servers that were involved in the transport. Check it if your server shows up.

@GeraldSchneider NDRs frequently don't include the full previous headers (which may be forged anyway), but they should contain a reference to the initial message ID which postfix should have logged if it was the origination.

@Zac67 some of the returns include the original email, which has a Message-ID field, but I don't see that message ID in my logs, so would that imply that they're faking returned emails to me?  and as you said, other returns don't include the original message, the only message id I see is the id of the return email sent to me

If you see logged message IDs on all regular mails but can't find those from the bounces then they're forged.

@Zac67 okay, that sounds pretty definitive.  If you want to submit an answer saying that (and maybe give a bit of info on what message id to look for?  I can post some example headers if it'd be useful), I can accept it as an answer?

Note there are two kinds of fake: 1A = someone just sends you a bogus NDR,which as you hint doesn't really accomplish anything; 1B = someone pretending to be you sends bogus/unwanted/harmful messages to real recipients, who respond by sending NDRs to the claimed originator = you, which is called a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_job

Postfix should log each processed message ID. The bounces/NDRs you receive should (at least) reference the original message ID - comparing that with your logs tells you whether the alleged mail came from your server or whether it was simply forged. As @dave_thompson has pointed out, it's also possible that the whole NDR is fake.
Using schemes like SPF, DKIM and/or DMARC 'protects' your domain from being abused by spammers - if you haven't already done so you might want to look into that.
